# Return parameters from Aws glue to step function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-step-functions, aws-step-config, aws-steps

I have a scenario of executing glue jobs from the step function. If i need to pass the parameters from first glue job to second glue job, How can i achieve that? I researched on it and didn't found any documentation on it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return output from AWS Glue jobs back to the calling Step Function workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58222209/how-to-return-output-from-aws-glue-jobs-back-to-the-calling-step-function-workfl)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Actually No, I have seen that post but it is long back, so just want to clarify if there is any way of doing that.

Comment: I don't have a great answer, but here's a couple of options.  1) Job1 drops the params in SQS and Job2 pulls them.  2) Use Glue Workflow in addition, or in place of, Step Functions for the Job orchestration.  Workflows have Properties and Job1 could add a Property that Job2 could access